# Convert 0.5 to 4.5 into 0 to 3.3 volt for adc input

Tags: voltage-regulator

I need to convert a voltage 0.5 to 4.5 which is output of the sensor into 0 to 3.3 voltage for an adc input.how I can??

Comment: How about a voltage divider?

Comment: Specify the exact sensor type and number.

Comment: Yeah. Unless you absolutely need every last bit of dynamic range, just use a voltage divider that converts 4.5 into 3.3. It will be much easier than trying to subtract out the 0.5V offset with analog circuitry.

Comment: okay..thank you. But can I convert the voltage range using op-amp?? if anyone knows tell me.

Comment: We need details of both the sensor and the ADC as input and output impedance may be important. Also would it be OK to invert the signal so 0.5V in gives 3.3V and 4.5V in gives 0V at the ADC?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the right place for such a question... but you can use a common voltage divider. For example, a 10k and a 3,7k resistor can be used. But pay attention for the maximum / minimum output load of your sensor! You did't give us any information about your application environement.